# What exactly cmake say: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ledit or /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurses?

Tags: linux, debug, build, makefile, cmake

I am using ubuntu 20.04.
I am doing debugging of building with cmake.
What exactly cmake say: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ledit`, i.e.what is `ledit`?
What is `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurses` exactly?
I need to know where is this error located for solving it.
example of cmake output:

```
--- stderr: real_time_tools                                                                                              
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ledit
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurses
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/real_time_tools.dir/build.make:190: libreal_time_tools.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:771: CMakeFiles/real_time_tools.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
---
```

Comment: what product are you trying to compile? where did you get the source, and what do the build instructions say about dependent packages?

Comment: Have you tried googling? First result when I do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary. Even if you don't find the answer, you will find how to troubleshoot this kind of issue with commands that help in troubleshooting, and you can post the output in your question. The more details you give, the better answers you can get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-ledit` and `-lcurses` are loader (`ld`) parameters.
The `-l` part means "library".

These messages mean that the `edit` and `curses` libraries were
not found, which means that the packages containing them were
not installed on the computer, but are needed for the link.

You need to find and install the missing packages for the link.
They are prerequisites of whatever program you are trying to build.

Comment: Specifically the development packages, not just the runtime ones.